# about venturi/bernuolli- what amount of pressure do I need to lift x amount of water?

Tags: bernoulli-equation

I'm trying to build a venturi pump/tee in which I want air to create a suction which lift a liquid (like they do in paint sprayers), lets say water.

My question is basically what is the minimal PSI of air i need to have in my tube in order to lift 1kg of water 1 meter up.

I have no idea how to calculate this and would really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important parameter in a Venturi is the flow velocity, not the pressure at the inlet. And the mass of the water doesn't come into it - it's the pressure difference (height difference) you need to worry about.

In your case, 1 m height difference of water requires a pressure difference of $10^4$ Pa (0.1 atm, since 10 m of water is 1 atm). If you are using air in your venturi, $\Delta P = \frac12 \rho v^2$ . You can find the velocity by solving:

$$v^2 = \frac{2\Delta P}{\rho}$$
$$v = 128 m/s$$

That seems pretty fast - but if you use a constricted nozzle, it is not so hard to achieve. For example, if you start with a tube that is 1 cm diameter and you constrict it to 2 mm diameter, the change in area is 25x so you need the inlet air to flow at approximately 5 m/s.

Comment: thank you very much for  your answer, Im afraid i must ask some very basic and ignorant questions  in return. first, why is it 10^4? isn't 1 atm=10^5so a tenth of it should be much less? second, what information did you use to get to the numeric 128m/s?  thank you very much!

Comment: third, if say the tube is constricted from 16mm to 3mm then wouldn't that create a problem of air coming back which would require more pressure? thank you very much!

Comment: $1 \text{atm}=10^5=100,000; 100,000 * 0.1 = 10,000 =10^4 Pa$. As for the second question, $128 = \sqrt{\frac{2*10,000}{1.22}}$ since the density of air is about 1.22 kg/m$^3$

Comment: And yes there will be some back pressure so your input pressure will be a little bit higher - depends on the geometry details of your nozzle.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I don't know how I didn't see it, here is another question which in retrospect might be dumb:P. why is \Delta P = \frac12 \rho v^2
 ? I read about dynamic pressure and if the equation there is \P = \frac12 \rho v^2
 then shouldn't Delta P  be  p1-p2? that is 1/2*roh*v(1)2-1/2*roh*v(2)2? 
 thx!